# Tiempo de vida de un variable dentro de una clase

Tags: java, array, jsp, lista

que tal tengo un proyecto donde se lee un archivo csv de miles de lineas una columna del csv la guardo y la envio a una clase donde alimenta una lista mi pregunta es cuanto tiempo de vida tiene dicha lista . una vez terminado se reiniciara . o como seria el tiempo de vida de dicha lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lista se mantendrá por todo el tiempo que esté el programa en ejecución. o mientras el objeto que contiene la lista no pase a ser nulo o sea re declarado. Ya que en caso de re declararse se tendrá que cargar la lista nuevamente.

Hay casos en los que java elimina "basura", pero esto ocurre solo cuando hay objetos "vivos", los cuales no se están utilizando  (Ninguna clase los ha instanciado).

Sin embargo no creo que ésto último sea tu caso.

Comment: el detalle es con jsp . por ejemplo si dicha jsp dura horas sin utilizarse o hasta dias dicha variable seguira viva ? . hasta que se cierre el sistema ? cierto ?

Comment: Así es. Se mantendrá hasta que no ocurra lo que te digo, no importa el tiempo.